# How can I design my DB to store versions of a record from a table, in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So I have designed a schema which has a "Car" table, and an "Insurance" table. As I represent in the ERD below, a car can have 0 or 1 insurance at one time, and an insurance may belong to one and only one car. So far so good.

The problem is, I want to know how much a person spent for insurance services in the past year.

As an example, let's say someone spends 100 on an insurance for 6 months, and then spends 100 again for the next 6 months.

I thought I could create another table which keeps all the records from the insurance table. I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do. Would it be a one to many relationship with the "Car" table, with the many side on the "Insurance history" table?

[image]

Comment: I would include a start and end date in the insurance table. That way you can use a single table to store the current insurance and the history.